# Assigning strings of any size to a pointer to char

Tags: c++, char

Before all, I must state that I'm a beginner with C++ and programming overall.
I'll get straight to the point. I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a string of characters of any size to a pointer to a character (not arrays, just a char * pointer). Would that violate any Memory Addresses?
The book I'm learning from doesn't seem to say anything about that. I can't seem to find anything on Google either.

Comment: `const char * ptr = "String of any size" ;` is valid. Unless you occupy whole read only location for string literals.

Comment: Do you mean that an error would occur if the string is too long? That is if the pointer points to a read only memory location, is that right?

Comment: What does "violate memory addresses" mean?

Answer (score 2):

You have your character pointer and want to dynamically create C strings

```
char *str;
```

say. This pointer will be used to point to the first character of the string. The string is a series of sequential characters (bytes) in memory. What we what to achieve this in memory:

```
 str -> +---+---+---+---+---+----+
        | H | E | L | L | O | \0 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Note the final byte - This byte has the value 0 and is call the null character - it represents the end of the string and enables one to easilty know when we have come to the end.

To give `str` a value ne allocate this memory. In C++ this is done by the `new operator` like this

```
str = new char[6];
```

*Note new has two versions new[] and new - one is to allocate an array of object, the other is to allocate a single object. ALWAYS use delete[] when you have allocated it with new[], similarly new/delete should be used. DO NOT MIX new[] with delete, and new with delete[]*

This will allocate an array of 6 characters to place the string into. To place the characters into the string we cold do this.

```
str[0] = `H`;
str[1] = `E];
...
str[5] = 0;
```

But this would be tedious. Instead we can use [strcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/) to do this for us:

```
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

It knows all about the null character. There is a range of functions that operate on these types of strings - please see [string](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/string/)

This is C strings. Once upon a time somebody invented this new language called C++. This language uses a different idea called objects that makes this stuff a lot easier. You need to look at the standard template library (or STL). Notes on these strings can be found at [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). There is lots of goodies in the STL - here is a reference [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.
Can you please explain why one would want to dynamically allocate memory for a user input string instead of just using a pointer. I'm confused as to why it's useful to use dynamic memory allocation for user input data instead of just strings.

Comment: Are you using C++ or C (as described above) strings?

Comment: I never worked with C, but if it helps I'm talking about using the new and delete operators in C++ to allocate memory.

Comment: C strings (as described above are arrays of characters. You can use them in C++. The normal way of allocating memory in C++ is new. In C it is malloc - but everything else is the same. The reason for dynamic allocation is because you do not know the size at compile time, you only find it out when the program is executed.

Comment: But in your code you called new[] with a constant, is it possible to call it with a variable?

Answer (score 1):

A `char` pointer can point to a string of any length, because the length of the string is determined by when you run into a `NUL` (0) byte in the string. When you store strings this way, it becomes a C-string. For instance:

```
const char* str = NULL; // at this point,
                        // doesn't point to anything (not even a string)

str = ""; // valid
str = "a"; // valid
str = "hello"; // valid
str = "farewell, cruel world"; // valid
```

Comment: Wouldn't a somewhat long string try to overwrite some read only memory locations?

Comment: Another question that comes to my mind is why would Dynamic Memory Operators new and delete be used to determine the size a pointer variable would occupy? Seems like one could make their pointers exactly as big as they want without having to use Dynamic Memory.
The book I'm learning from uses new and delete to make pointers only as big as they need to be, which seems really weird according to what I can understand from you.

Comment: @T0rm3nt0R, all of the strings in Seth's example are likely to be in read-only memory if that's what you're asking.  If a string comes from user input, then it might very well be useful to allocate space for the string dynamically.

Comment: That's the question I'm trying to ask. Why and when is it more reasonable to allocate space dynamically for a string in memory?
If a pointer would take a string of any size, then no matter how long the string the user enters it'll "fit" in the pointer. So why would I want to use dynamic memory to allocate space for the string input by the user?